# How can I execute ssh command in linux with specific flags without the need of an alias

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to use this ssh command with those flags every time I want to connect via ssh to a host since they will create an ssh session with stronger cipher and compression to make sessions faster and stronger.

Obviously I would like to save some typing and not have to type all the long command every time I want to connect to a host:

```
ssh -4 -C -c blowfish-cbc user@hostname
```

Could anyone tell me how can I execute the command without the need to create an alias?

Comment: Why is creating an alias off the table?

Comment: Because is not ideal. for example, if someone else uses the computer to connect to a remote host and for some reason those flags cause any trouble he wouldn't know what is causing the problem 'ssh' should be always executed as ssh and not a modified version of the original binary.

Comment: Are you sharing a user with someone else? If no, your alias will not apply to them; it's in *your* user's `.bashrc` file, not theirs. If yes, why not create some random alias? That is, something you'll remember but others would not accidentally type.

Comment: I want to make it permanent for ALL the users of the computer

Comment: I don't know why this question got downvoted. Hopefully someone can explain that before doing it.

Comment: I explained why I cast a downvote. Its completely off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The down vote is for the quality of the question and if the question is not about any programming layer. if this is off-topic just vote for off-topic, but down vote is a different thing. There are tons of questions about linux on this platform and they don't get down vote for that. Please stick to the terms of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be set in your [ssh config file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config). Which should be placed in `~/.ssh/config`. For local users, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for global users.

Example of a configuration that is for a specific connection.

```
Host foo
    User myusername
    HostName mycomputer.com
    Port 22
    Ciphers blowfish-cbc
    Compression yes
    AddressFamily inet
```

Example of a configuration that will work for everything you try to connect to (unless overridden).

```
Host *
    Port 22
    Ciphers blowfish-cbc
    Compression yes
    AddressFamily inet
```

The first example is accessed by calling `ssh foo`. The configuration settings **only** effect that machine. This allows you to have a lot less hassle when you use multiple keys

The second example will apply settings to all hosts (note the `*`), unless they're overwritten by either a command or a different configuration.

Comment: The problem is that those option will work only for that specific host not for every host.

Comment: @VaTo sure it can. Place the file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and set the top line to `Host *`.

Comment: @VaTo: You'll need to remove the User and HostName from it though.

Comment: @Vato: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/making-ssh-hosts-global-to-all-the-users-on-the-computer) for more info.

Comment: Why do I need to include the line Host * at the top of the file? Doesn't all the configuration apply for all hosts already?

Comment: Thank you, I think I got what I need. Do you know if there's any way to verify if the options got applied when I'm connecting or connected.

Comment: @VaTo: If you turn on debugging, you should see exactly what it's doing. Try enabling `LogLevel Debug3` (very high level of debugging) temporarily. Then you can check the logs. Do **not** leave this on long term. It'll use a ton of disk space over time.